# Keeping original format on file rename using AngularJS and ng File Upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm using the [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) to upload images in a web app.

Upload process works good, but when I try to give each file a unique name using momentJS, **it won't automatically keep the format** and save it without file extension.

For example, **image.jpg will become 12-07-2016-23-36-44**.

I managed to fix this using the following code, but then it will save all images to JPG even if they are not (PNG, GIF...)

```
$scope.uniquelogo = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY-HH-mm-ss') + '.jpg';

Upload.upload({
   url: 'upload.php',
   data: {
    file: file,
    name: Upload.rename(file, $scope.uniquelogo)
   }
```

How could I use Upload.rename() and still keep the original file format?

Comment: Can you get the extension from the original filename and use that instead of `.jpg`?

Comment: @MikeC I don't see anything about it in the documentation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the property **type** to get the extension, **but** it comes for example:

1. **image/(jpeg|png)**
2. **video/mp4**

So you can use the `string` methods [**`String.prototype.substring()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) + [**`String.prototype.lastIndexOf()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) to get only the part that you want:

```
name: Upload.rename(file, $scope.uniquelogo + file.name.substring(file.type.lastIndexOf('/'), file.name.length).replace('/', '.'));
```

**Note:** I used the replace method to replace the `"/"` for `"."`, but you can also do it by hand (just putting `$scope.uniquelogo + '.' + file.name.substring(file.type.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, file.name.length)`

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the extension from the original file name and use that instead of `.jpg`.

```
function getFileExtension(filename) {
  return filename
    .split('.')    // Split the string on every period
    .slice(-1)[0]; // Get the last item from the split
}

$scope.uniquelogo = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY-HH-mm-ss');

Upload.upload({
   url: 'upload.php',
   data: {
    file: file,
    name: Upload.rename(file, $scope.uniquelogo + getFileExtension(file.name))
   }
   ...
```